# How to use same variable to receive intent extra from 2 different classes?

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I have a variable in a class which gets intent extra value from viewHolder A like this

```
 var artistName = intent.getStringExtra(viewHolderA.ARTIST_NAME)
```

now let say I have viewHolder B and I want to pass a value to artistName as well

```
 var artistName = intent.getStringExtra(viewHolderB.ARTIST_NAME)
```

is there a way to check if intent.getStringExtra from viewHolderA is empty then getStringExtra from viewholder B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find the answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I should use `intent.hasExtra()` to check if `viewHolderA` or `viewHolderB` has value then get the value from whichever `viewHolder` has value.

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't set the string extra `viewHolderA.ARTIST_NAME` as `""`, then `intent.getStringExtra(viewHolderA.ARTIST_NAME)` will return `null` or some meaningful value.

In that case,

```
var artistName = intent.getStringExtra(viewHolderA.ARTIST_NAME) ?: intent.getStringExtra(viewHolderB.ARTIST_NAME)
```

This is equal to

```
var artistName: String? = null
if (intent.getStringExtra(viewHolderA.ARTIST_NAME) == null) {
    artistName = intent.getStringExtra(viewHolderB.ARTIST_NAME)
} else {
    artistName = intent.getStringExtra(viewHolderA.ARTIST_NAME)
}
```

using the [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator).

---

If we are not sure whether `viewHolderA.ARTIST_NAME` can be `""` or not,
you can use

```
var artistName = if (intent.getStringExtra(viewHolderA.ARTIST_NAME).isNullOrEmpty()) {
    intent.getStringExtra(viewHolderB.ARTIST_NAME)
} else {
    intent.getStringExtra(viewHolderA.ARTIST_NAME)
}
```

because `if (condition) A else B` in Kotlin is the same as `condition ? A : B` in Java. (Here, the method `isNullOrEmpty()` is true when it is either `null` or `""`.)